# Components seem not update between multiple actions dispatched from same thunk when making async calls?

Tags: react-native, redux-thunk

Using react-native, do components not update between multiple actions dispatched from same thunk when calling from mapDispatchToProps? Asking because my use case is: trying to do an async API request from a thunk action creator, but setting and unsetting an isFetching flag in between to display a loading spinner overlay on the screen like so:

```js
// ComponentPresenter.js
export default class SigninScreenPresenter extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    componentDidUpdate() {
        console.log(`isFetching=${this.props.isFetching}`)
    }
    handlePress = () => {
        this.props.stateCallback()
    }
    render() {
        return(
        <SomeOtherStuff onPress={this.handlePress.bind(this)}/>
        <Spinner visible={this.props.isFetching} textContent={"Loading..."} textStyle={{color: '#FFF'}} />
        )
    }
}



// ComponentContainer.js
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    // checking state changes
    console.log(`mapping state to props: state.session.isFetching=${state.session.isFetching}`)
    return {
        isFetching: state.session.isFetching,
        ownProps: ownProps
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  return {
      stateCallback: () => {
          dispatch(apiRequestThunk())
        }
  }
}

const ComponentContainer = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(ComponentPresenter)

export default ComponentContainer



// actions/index.js
.....
export function setFetchingFlag() {
    return {type: SET_FETCHING}
}
export function unsetFetchingFlag() {
    return {type: UNSET_FETCHING}
}
export function apiRequestThunk() {
    return function (dispatch) {
        dispatch(setFetchingFlag())
        fetch(...making some REST request...)
            .then(
                (res) => {dispatch(someSuccessAction())}, 
                (error) => {dispatch(someFailureAction())})
        dispatch(unsetFetchingFlag())
    }
}
.....



// reducers/index.js
.....
const sessionReducer = (state=initialState.session, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FLAG_API_REQUEST:
            console.log('fetching API request')
            return Object.assign({}, state, {isFetching: true})
        case UNFLAG_API_REQUEST:
            console.log('done fetching API request')
            return Object.assign({}, state, {isFetching: false})
        default:
            return state
    }
}
.....
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    session: sessionReducer,
    otherStateFields: otherReducers,
    .....
})
export default rootReducer
```

the console output I see when firing handlePress() in the presenter component is

```
[14:49:03] fetching API request   (from reducers)
[14:49:03] mapping state to props: state.session.isFetching=true   (from container)
[14:49:03] done fetching API request    (from reducer)
[14:49:03] mapping state to props: state.session.isFetching=false    (from container)
[14:49:03] In component presenter: isFetching=false    (from presenter (I would expect another one before this with isFetching=True))
```

and the Spinner never renders.

Notice there is no output "In component presenter: isFetching=true" (as if it never reads from the mapping-to-state, even though the output suggests that it is being called). This makes it seem like the component is not acutally updating with the mapStateToProps values until after the mapDispatchToCallback function called in the presenter component is **finished** executing.

Is there something else wrong here? Is there a more 'best-practice' way to do this? New to thunk and redux, so any debugging advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to call `dispatch(unsetFetchingFlag())` once the async request has been resolved/rejected. Here you are starting the loader, then sending the **async** request. This is fine. However, **without waiting for the request to resolve you are unsetting the loader**. I believe that is the issue. Check it out this solution.

```
export function apiRequestThunk() {
    return dispatch => {
        // Start the loader
        dispatch(setFetchingFlag());

        // Send the async request
        fetch(...making some REST request...)
            .then(res => {
              // The request has been resolved. So stop the loader. 
              dispatch(someSuccessAction());
              dispatch(unsetFetchingFlag());
            }) 
            .catch(error => {
              // An error has occurred. So 
              // 1. Stop the loader. 
              // 2. Display the error, if require
              dispatch(unsetFetchingFlag());
              dispatch(someFailureAction());
            });
    }
}
```

**Using async/await**

```
export function apiRequestThunk() {
  return async dispatch => {
      // Start the loader
      dispatch(setFetchingFlag());

      try {
        // Send the async request
        const response= await fetch(...making some REST request...);

        // Once the request gets resolved, stop the loader. 
        // If any error occur in the request, then the error will be caught in the 'catch' block
        dispatch(someSuccessAction());
        dispatch(unsetFetchingFlag());
      }
      catch(error) {
        // An error has occurred. So 
        // 1. Stop the loader. 
        // 2. Display the error, if required
        dispatch(unsetFetchingFlag());
        dispatch(someFailureAction());
      }
  }
}
```

Also no need to bind **this** to the `onPress` since you are already using arrow function. `<SomeOtherStuff onPress={this.handlePress}/>`

Comment: Note that using `.then().catch()` seems to be discouraged when using redux-thunk  (though I'm new to redux, so could be mistaken). See the example here https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions#actions-js-asynchronous and this github issue https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/6895#issuecomment-281405036. What should be done instead is use the `onFulfilled` and `onRejected` callbacks within just the `.then()` of the promise (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then).